# Is there a way to reopen a site exactly how it was in headless in "headless: false" mode?

Tags: node.js, post, cookies, get, puppeteer

So if I went to a site that has a feature that after 50 seconds on it, it does something on the page and the HTML changes, is it possible to do that in headless mode, and then collect cookies once 50 seconds has passed, and then re-open in non-headless using those cookies so I can see the HTML that should be displayed after 50 seconds. Is this possible in Puppeteer (JS) and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are APIs available to [waitFor](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) some seconds and to [get the cookies](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls). To be able to reuse the cookies, you should also use the [`userDataDir` argument](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerdefaultargsoptions) which would store the cookies in first run and reuse them in subsequent ones.

Comment: So I am able to re-open the site and see the exact same thing I saw after 50 seconds went past in the first time, because of cookies? Do cookies store exactly how the site was when I accessed it the first time I guess is what I'm asking again?

Comment: That really depends on a website if it uses cookies and how it uses them. Even if it uses them, it may or may not use them to present the page differently to different users. "Do cookies store exactly how the site was when I accessed it the first time": not really clear what you meant by this.